# Не удаляются куки после выхода

Tags: php

Почему куки остаются и после переадресации страницы массив кук не выводится?
И что значит перед отправкой заголовком setcookie, header не должно быть вывода?

**index.php**

```
<?php error_reporting(-1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

if(isset($_POST['login']) && filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) && ($_POST['password'])){
    setcookie('name', $_POST['login'], time()+3600*24*30, '/');
    setcookie('email', $_POST['email'], time()+3600*24*30, '/');
    setcookie('password', $_POST['password'], time()+3600*24*30, '/');
    header('Location: index2.php');
}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Авторизация</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="login" style="border: 1px solid; width: 220px; clear: both; overflow: hidden">
<p style="text-align: center;">Вход</p>
    <form action="" method="post">
        <div style="clear: both;">
            <span style="float: left">Логин:</span> <input type="text" name="login" style="float: right; width: 150px;">
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;">
            <span style="float: left">Email:</span> <input type="text" name="email" style="float: right; width: 150px;">
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both;">
            <span style="float: left">Пароль:</span> <input type="text" name="password" style="float: right; width: 150px;">
        </div>
        <div style="margin-top: 30px; overflow: hidden">
            <input type="submit" value="Войти" style="float: right;">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

**index2.php**

```
<?php error_reporting(-1);
header('Content-Type: text/html; char set=utf-8');
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');

if(isset($_GET['exit']) && $_GET['exit'] == 1){
    setcookie('name', "", time() - 3600, '/');
    header('Location: index.php');
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($_COOKIE);
    echo '</pre>';
    exit();
}

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Личный кабинет</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    echo 'Ваш логин: ' . $_COOKIE['name'] . '<br>';
    echo 'Ваш email: ' . $_COOKIE['email'] . '<br>';
    echo 'Ваш пароль: ' . $_COOKIE['password'] . '<br>';

    ?>
    <form action="" method="GET">
        <input type="hidden" name="exit" value="1">
        <a href="index.php?exit=1">Выход</a>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну смотрите. У вас во втором файле есть скрипт удаления куков и т.п. В этом же файле ниже форма для выхода с ссылкой вида

```
<a href="index.php?exit=1">Выход</a>
```

Вы же сами себя отправляете для выхода на первый файл, где скрипта удаления нет.

Вообще очень у вас всё коряво и запутано. В итоге сами же и запутались. Понимаете?

Не понимаете. Исправьте в index2.php код выше на код ниже

```
<a href="index2.php?exit=1">Выход</a>
```

Comment: а зачем помещать ссылку в форму? кстати, не рекомендую выводить пользователю его пароль в кабинете. да и тем более хранить его в `куках`. `куки` можно красть и просматривать, они хранятся на стороне клиента.

Comment: @webDev_ Причём тут я? Ты это ему пиши. Я лишь указал на ошибку. Исправить на index2.php - и куки удаляются. Вопрос решён. Другого не спрашивают.

Comment: вынес ссылку за форму и всё равно куки не удаляются

Comment: @DivMan что вы сделали?! за какую форму вы ссылку вынесли? вы о чём? Вы заработались. Идите отдыхайте.

Comment: я уже 2 дня отдыхал. Я не понимаю, почему переадресация работает, а удаление нет?

Comment: @DivMan я дополнил ответ. посмотрите. И прочитайте ещё раз всё внимательно.

Comment: изменил и после выхода мне пишет Object not found!

Comment: @DivMan там опечатка была. смотрите сейчас.

Comment: спасибо, заработало

Comment: @DivMan вы хоть поняли в чём дело?

Comment: @DivMan Буду благодарен, если отметите мой ответ как ответ на ваш вопрос.

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: @DivMan тут (http://i.imgur.com/iFTvQoZ.png) должна быть галочка - её видите только вы. Если нажать, то она станет зелёной. Так вы отметите, что сообщение является ответом на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @DivMan благодарю. Успехов!

Comment: @n.osennij чутка промазал, или сайт меня подвёл. хотел написать выше.